# python code for Exporting scraped data to CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, web-scraping

```
import csv     
in_txt = csv.reader(open(post.text, "rb"), delimiter = '\t')    
out_csv = csv.writer("C:\Users\sptechsoft\Documents\source3.csv", 'wb')    
out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

when executing above code i am getting IO error and i need to save in CSV in seperate folder

[image: Output shown as IO error]

Comment: post.text is my file the data is showing as IO error and that data should be stored in CSV as seperate folder

Comment: change `open(post.text, "rb")` to `"post.text"`
Error is self explanatory

Comment: `post` is a variable. `post.text` is a attribute. `"post.text"` is a **filename**

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to open file before passing it to csvreader.
You can directly pass the file to csvreader and it would work

```
import csv     
in_txt = csv.reader("post.text", "rb", delimiter = '\t')    
out_csv = csv.writer("C:\Users\sptechsoft\Documents\source3.csv", 'wb')    
out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

Comment: I execute the same thing but saying unknown Dialect

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import csv     

with open(post.text, "rb") as f_input, open(r"C:\Users\sptechsoft\Documents\source3.csv", "wb") as f_output:
    in_csv = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t')    
    out_csv = csv.writer(f_output)    
    out_csv.writerows(in_csv)
```

The `csv.reader()` and `csv.writer()` needs either a list or a file object. It cannot open the file for you. By using `with` it ensures the files are correctly closed automatically afterwards.

Also do not forget to prefix your path string with `r` to disable any string escaping due to the backslashes.

Comment: same as above error the data coming as IO error but not storing in seperate CSV

Comment: Try `print post.text`, it needs to be a filename, ideally with a full path.

Comment: Note, your filename must not contain additional quotes, i.e. `"test.csv"` is not valid. If this is the case, replace `post.text` with `post_text.strip('"\'')`. If it does have quotes, you will get an IOError.